# Pattern for client-side update in SOA

Tags: wcf, design-patterns, repository-pattern, soa, dto

I want to develop a data-driven WPF application, which uses WCF to connect to the server-side, which itself uses NHibernate to persist data. For examle there is a domain-object called "Customer" and there is also a flattened (with Automapper) "CustomerDTO" which is returned by a WCF-operation called "GetCustomer(int customerId)".

I don't know where I should make data-validation and how I should handle client-side updating, so that one could modify single or multiple properties on the client by editing a form and finally clicking "save"...

Could you please provide me with some common patterns in such a situation or any best-pratice examples, which target real LOB-applications (n-tiered pattern, multiple layers, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good fit for [Self Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321569.aspx#id0090017). Be aware that STE's are hot off the press and still have a bit more maturing to do. The approach used with them should answer your common patterns question.